# "others" refers in a sentence

Tags: pronouns

> Different  people  have  different  ideas  of  beauty  or  handsomeness.  You  only  have  to  look  at those  around you to realize  that  people are  attracted by  every  possible physical  type. Some people  find plumpness  attractive.  Some  go  for  black  hair;  **others,** brown.

From above sentence, what does the bold word "others"
refer to? Only in my point of view, I think it may be "some other people" as I think it refers to "additional people".

Comment: It refers to "people" but it is interpreted anaphorically as "other people". We understand that "Some people find plumpness attractive; some people go for black hair and **other people** go for brown hair.

Answer (score 7):

It means other people.

The sentence could be rewritten as

> Some people go for black hair; other people go for brown hair.

Answer (score 7):

> Some people find plumpness attractive, some people find black hair attractive, other people like brown hair.

"Others" is a pronoun that refers back to "people".  It simply means "other people, different from those previously mentioned".